# Trying to change AJAX url parameter based on click event

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to change the AJAX URL parameter based on a click event. For example, I have a database such as:

http://test/test/test/state/NJ

This can be change to reflect data for a certain state. So if you type 'FL' instead of 'NJ' at the end of the url, it shows data for Florida instead of NJ. My problem is that I am working with a map of the USA and when you click on a certain state, I need the click event to dynamically change the AJAX url. Please see the code below thanks. Im not sure why the click event wont change the data url parameter.

```
 $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: $(this).data('url'),
        cache: true,
        success: function(json){     

        }
});

$('#mapWhereToBuy').usmap({
  click: function(event, data) {
    var description = "Sorry. We do not carry products in this state.";
    switch(data.name)
    {

        case 'NJ':
            description = 'New Jersey';
            $(this).attr('data-url', 'http://test/test/test/state/NJ');
            break;
        case 'PA':
            description = 'Pennsylvania';
             $(this).attr('data-url', 'http://test/test/test/state/PA');
            break;
    }

  $('#clicked-state').text(description); 

  }
});

console.log($(this).data('url'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making it's few difficult. You can fire ajax inside `.usmap`. See below example.

```
$('#map').usmap({ 
  click: function(event, data) {
     switch(data.name){
         case 'NJ':
             description = 'New Jersey'; 
             break;
         case 'PA':
             description = 'Pennsylvania'; 
             break;
         default:
             description = 'Sorry. We do not carry products in this state.'; 
             break;

     }
     $.ajax({
          dataType: "jsonp",
          url: 'http://test/test/test/state/'+data.name,
          cache: true,
          success: function(json){
             //Organized ajax returned data from here.
          }
      }); 
  }
});
```